# CDH5.3.5 zookeeper start failed

Tags: apache-zookeeper

After upgrading CDH5.3.2 to CDH5.3.5, zookeeper start failed, I got

> Command aborted because of exception: Command timed-out after 150 seconds

in cloudera manager, and I got this error code in log file

```
2015-07-20 19:45:50,771 ERROR org.apache.zookeeper.server.NIOServerCnxn: Unexpected Exception:
java.nio.channels.CancelledKeyException
    at sun.nio.ch.SelectionKeyImpl.ensureValid(SelectionKeyImpl.java:73)
    at sun.nio.ch.SelectionKeyImpl.interestOps(SelectionKeyImpl.java:77)
    at org.apache.zookeeper.server.NIOServerCnxn.sendBuffer(NIOServerCnxn.java:153)
    at org.apache.zookeeper.server.NIOServerCnxn.sendResponse(NIOServerCnxn.java:1075)
    at org.apache.zookeeper.server.NIOServerCnxn.process(NIOServerCnxn.java:1112)
    at org.apache.zookeeper.server.WatchManager.triggerWatch(WatchManager.java:120)
    at org.apache.zookeeper.server.WatchManager.triggerWatch(WatchManager.java:92)
    at org.apache.zookeeper.server.DataTree.deleteNode(DataTree.java:594)
    at org.apache.zookeeper.server.DataTree.killSession(DataTree.java:966)
    at org.apache.zookeeper.server.DataTree.processTxn(DataTree.java:818)
    at org.apache.zookeeper.server.ZKDatabase.processTxn(ZKDatabase.java:329)
    at org.apache.zookeeper.server.ZooKeeperServer.processTxn(ZooKeeperServer.java:965)
    at org.apache.zookeeper.server.FinalRequestProcessor.processRequest(FinalRequestProcessor.java:116)
    at org.apache.zookeeper.server.quorum.Leader$ToBeAppliedRequestProcessor.processRequest(Leader.java:634)
    at org.apache.zookeeper.server.quorum.CommitProcessor.run(CommitProcessor.java:74)
```

what should I do to get zookeeper start successful? thanks very much